# Loop through first cells of selected merged ranges only

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to give the user the option to do simple arithmetic operations on selected cells.
The thing is that most cells are merged ranges.

I got the following already but the problem with it is that it loops through all cells while I only want it to only affect those cells that are not merged or only to the first cells of merged ranges.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    myValue = InputBox("Enter")
    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        On Error Resume Next
        cel.Value = Evaluate(cel.Value & myValue)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## The MergeCells Property

Using the **MergeCells** property in an **If** statement, you check if a cell is not merged, **then** execute the following statement(s), otherwise the statement(s) after **Else**.

In the following example, the range **I3:M12** is selected and **5** is entered as **myValue**. The first table is the state of the second table before.

[image]

### The Code

```
Sub test()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim myValue As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    myValue = InputBox("Enter")

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        If Not cel.MergeCells Then
            ' If not merged cell.
            cel.Value = Evaluate(cel.Value & myValue)
          Else
            ' if merged cell.
            cel.Value = Evaluate(cel.Value + myValue)
        End If
    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

### Count

We can expand the previous tables by adding a **COUNT** column,

[image]

where it is more obvious how the merged cells are being 'ignored' in Excel i.e. all cells except the first cell of a merged area will not be counted (or summed up, or ...).

The following shows the difference between counting the cells in VBA and in Excel.

```
Sub MergeTest()
    With Range("J3:J12")
        Debug.Print .Cells.Count
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Count(.Cells)
    End With
    With Range("J3:N12")
        Debug.Print .Cells.Count
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Count(.Cells)
    End With
End Sub
```

The results in the Immediate window are

*10*,
**9**,
*50*,
**46**,

which shows how *VBA* will count every cell, but **Excel** will exclude all cells of a merged area except the first.

In VBA Help search for the **MergeArea** property for some further info.

Answer (score 0):

Although *VBasic2008*'s answer works, it's not totally correct. The problem is that *each* cell in merged range always returns `True` for `MergedCells` property. This means that excessive processing is done in a loop (i.e. incrementing a value) for cells other than top-left cell. To fix this situation, you should test each cell for the need to process. You can do this in several ways:

1. You can compare the address of a cell with the top-left cell address (`Option 1` in code).
2. You can test the length of cell's value. If it's zero, then it's not top-left cell, so you skip it (`Option 2` in code).

Code:

```
Sub IncrValues()

    Dim rng As Range, myValue%

    myValue = InputBox("Enter")

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            '// Option 1:
            If cell.Address = cell.MergeArea(1).Address Then
                cell.Value = cell.Value + myValue
            End If
            '// Option 2:
            'If Len(cell) > 0 Then
            '    cell.Value = cell.Value + myValue
            'End If
        Else
            cell.Value = cell.Value + myValue
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```